# NextJS 13 page returns 404 when the previous page with different search parameters also returns 404

Tags: next.js, next.js13

This is basic example of my page file for '/products' route

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default function Page({ searchParams }) {
  if (searchParams['tag'] === 'dummy')
    notFound()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='mb-4'>Products Page</h1>
      <Link href='/products?tag=dummy' className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full'>
        Filter by tag dummy 
      </Link>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(searchParams)}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I go to '/products', it returns all products normally, then I go to '/products?tag=dummy' with the Link component, it returns 200 with not found file, but when going back to '/products' it keeps returning the not found file.

What I've been doing is inside not-found.js listen to searchSearch with useEffect and use `window.location.reload()`, because `router.refresh()` from `next/navigation` shows the same not-found.js file. But I don't think this is a the good way.

What I was expecting is to see previous page showing up instead of not-found.js when going back without the need of refresing the page.

I'm using NextJS 13.4.9.